# How to pass large data from parent fragment to child fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a parent fragment which I call the main fragment. Main fragment hosts a wiew pager which have two fragments, so I have a main fragment and it hosts two fragments.

I want to download json data from my main fragment and I want to pass some of it to first fragment and some of it to second fragment.

I can pass data with bundles, but bundles have memory limits, so I don't tend to do it with bundles, because the data is big

How can I manage this situation ? thank you

Comment: What problem you have passing it over bundle as arguments?

Comment: I read that bundles has some limits, so that is why I don't use them, I am looking for other options

Comment: i assume you are downloading the json data in a background Service, aren't you? so bind to that Service from anything you want (fragment1, fragment 2 etc)

Comment: @pskink yes I do use services for downloading my json, how can I bind to that, I have no idea how to do it, If you could give me the keywords, I will search it and learn, thanks :)

Comment: keywords: "android bound services", just ask uncle google, of course you will need "local bound service" pattern (section "Extending the Binder class")

Comment: @pskink thank you, I am searching right now

Comment: i'm 100% sure you will find the document i'm talking about ;-)

Comment: @pskink I am still stuck at this point, as I understand from your point of view, you mean to subscribe fragments to service, and publish data to fragments, is it right ?

Comment: did you find "local bound service" pattern?

Comment: I get the point now :) thank you, I can mark your answer as the best answer, if you could answer this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i assume you are downloading the json data in a background `Service`, aren't you? so bind to that `Service` from anything you want (fragment1, fragment 2 etc). make sure you are using "local bound service" pattern so you can simply cast `service` parameter of `onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)` to your local binder, for more info refer to: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand? Just pass the data through a method

So parentFragment has a reference to childFragment1 and childFragment2

in child fragment:

```
public void giveMeTheData(Object someData){
      //do something with data
}
```

in parent fragment:

```
ChildFragment1 childFragment

onResume(){
     childFragment.giveMeTheData(obj)
}
```